# c++ visual studio windows form possible scope issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio

making a game where money increments each second depending on businesses owned. Money should stop incrementing when business is sold but doesn't. Here are all the methods involved.
I'm thinking maybe the remove business method isn't permanently erasing it, any ideas?

```
uname.sell(name);
uname.addMoney(sellValue);

void User::sell(std::string b)
{
    Business temp = this->current.getBusiness(b);

    this->addMoney(temp.getCost() * 0.8);
    this->getCurrent().removeBusiness(temp);
}

//removes business from the map

void Map::removeBusiness(Business b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < businesses.size(); i++)
    {
        if (businesses[i].getName() == b.getName()) {
            &businesses.erase(businesses.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}

void User::payday()
{
    double paySum = 0;
    // loops through all the stored maps
    for (int i = 0; i < maps.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<Business> temp = maps[i].getBusinesses();
        // Go through temp, finding the bus
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
        paySum += temp[j].getPay(); // Sum the pay for all business 
        }   
    }
    addMoney(paySum);
 }
```

Comment: `I'm thinking maybe the remove business method isn't permanently erasing it` what have you done to prove/disprove this hypothesis?